# Copy content of latest /newest folder windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I have something that makes a new folder with files in every night. Does anyone know how to create a script that will copy the content of the newest/latest folder to a network share and overwrite any of the files and folders in the network share? Been scratching my head for awhile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this might serve your purpose:

```
SET "src_root=D:\root\for\source\directories"
SET "tgt_path=\\NETWORK\SHARE\target\path"

DIR "%src_root%" /B /AD /O-D /TC > "%TEMP%\dirlist.tmp"
< "%TEMP%\dirlist.tmp" SET /P last_dir=

FOR /D %%I IN ("%tgt_path%\*") DO RD "%%I" /S /Q
DEL "%tgt_path%\*" /Q

XCOPY "%src_root%\%last_dir%\*" "%tgt_path%" /S /E
```

The `src_root` variable is supposed to contain the path to the folder where your daily folders are created, and `tgt_path` is the target path for the latest folder's contents to copy.

The `DIR` command is set up to return the contents of the root folder in the following manner:

- no extra information in the output, only names (`/B`);
- no files, just folders (`/AD`);
- sort (`/O…`) the output in the descending (`…-…`) order of folder date (`…D`);
- the date is that of the folder's creation (`/TC`).

The output is redirected to a temporary file, whose first line is then read into a variable (the `SET /P` command). That piece of information, together with the root path and the target path, is ultimately used first with deleting, then with copying files.

The deleting is done in two steps: first the folders (the `RD` command in the `FOR /D` loop), then the files (`DEL`). I'd like to note at this point that this script doesn't assume intervention at any stage on your side, which I understood was your intention. Consequently, it doesn't expect a confirmation to delete the files and folders at the target path, so, when you run the script, the old contents will be deleted *silently* (which is the effect of the `/Q` switch used with both `RD` and `DEL`).

The copying is done with `XCOPY`, as it allows us to retain the structure of the source folder (the `/S` switch), including empty subdirectories (`/E`), if any.

You can get more information on every command mentioned here by invoking any of them with the `/?` switch at the command prompt.

Comment: That works brilliantly, thank you very much and thank you for explaining each step!

Comment: Brilliant small script, thanks Andriy! I wrote something similar for bash couple of month ago, but was too lazy to think, so looked it up on SO and "voila". Small warning: this script will silently DELETE EVERYTHING in the target dir. So be careful to point it to a new empty folder.

Comment: @AlexPakka: Thank you for the kind words, I'm glad you've found this useful. You are perfectly right, this script will indeed delete everything silently. I understood that would agree with the OP's requirements, as they specifically indicated they wanted the target's contents overwritten. However, now that you've specifically mentioned that I think it will be a good idea to point it out in my post as well (and I'm doing it straight away), so thanks for that too!

Comment: @Andry M - Wanted to do exactly same thing and Thanks a lot for the script and explanation